While installing chatterbot on Python, I am getting an error
While executing the Command 'pip install chatterbot' on Powershell, I am getting the error 'Cannot import name 'msvccompiler' from 'distutils'. Why?[enter image Original Execution process(as usual)Error](https://i.sstatic.net/maC7rWDs.png)
I was originally trying to create an AI chatbot using python, so I was trying to install the chatterbot module on python.Note: I DO NOT HAVE VISUAL C++

Please post the complete output as text here, not links to images.

Use python version 3.8.10 .

The current latest stable version ChatterBot 1.0.8 was released in 2020. Requires Python >=3.4, <=3.8.
Use Python 3.8 to install ChatterBot.

Two years ago, distutils was completely removed starting from Python 3.10 and later, and users were advised to make necessary changes to their codebases. If you're encountering errors related to distutils with packages like chatterbot, it often indicates that the package has not been updated in over two years. In such cases, it may be necessary to find alternative packages that are actively maintained and compatible with newer versions of Python.
